# warning: XXXX has different visibility (default) in YYYY and (hidden) in ZZZZ

Tags: iphone, c++, opencv

I am trying to make an iPhone app that uses OpenCV plus another C++ Library.
It seems to compile and link fine. It actually works.
Is just I want to get rid of this ugly warning:

```
ld: warning: std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int const&)has different visibility (default) in /Users/nacho4d/Documents/Projects/iOS/iAR/opencv_device/lib/libcxcore.a(cxdatastructs.o) and (hidden) in /Users/nacho4d/Documents/Projects/iOS/iAR/build/iAR.build/Debug-iphoneos/iAR.build/Objects-normal/armv6/combination.o
```

What does it mean?, How can I solve it?

just in case, this is the header of combination class, from the library I mentioned.

```
//combination.h
typedef std::vector<int> combi;
typedef std::vector< combi > allcombi;
class Combination
{
public:
    void Init(const int n, const int m);
    allcombi::iterator begin();
    allcombi::iterator end();
    allcombi::const_iterator begin() const;
    allcombi::const_iterator end() const;
private:
    void Nest(int nest, int column, int n1, int n2, int k[], allcombi &result);
private:
    allcombi m_data;
};
```

Thanks in advance

Ignacio

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a dupe.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems `libcxcore.a` and `combination.o` are compiled with different symbol visibility options.

Read about symbol visibility [there](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/CppRuntimeEnv/Articles/SymbolVisibility.html).

So, I guess you just need to compile `combination.cpp` with `-fvisibility=default` flag. If you use XCode, check "Symbols Hidden by Default" setting in "GCC - Code Generation" section. It should be unchecked for both projects.

[image]

Comment: I have tried #pragma GCC visibility push(default) class Combination and the warning didn't go away. I also have checked Xcode and "Symbols Hidden by Defaults" is unchecked. What other options do I have? (+1 for the link ;)  )

Comment: Wait!. I just tried checking, compiling and unchecking Symbols Hidden by default and the warning are gone! Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: It worked out for me too when I was using funambol sdk in my application.

Comment: Also had to check and then uncheck "Symbols Hidden by default" to get rid of the warnings... For some reason, the target and project settings didn't match while there was no setting modification reported at target level :/